# How to call a function in haskell?

Tags: haskell, random, io, program-entry-point, shuffle

I have a code that creates a list and then shuffle  it. But i cannot execute because a problem with the `=` in the `main = do` section. The error is `"parse error on input"`.

This is the code:

```
import System.IO
import System.Random

shuffle :: [a] -> [a]
shuffle list = if length list < 2 then return list else do
i <- randomRIO (0, length list-1)
r <- shuffle (take i list ++ drop (i+1) list)
return (list!!i : r)

main = do  --the problem is in this line
   putStrLn "Enter the number:"  
   number <- getLine  
   let n = (read number :: Int)
   let list = [1..n]
   print list
   shuffle list
```

Comment: The `do` in the `shuffle` does not make much sense. A list is indeed an instance of the monad typeclass, but here you `return` a list, so basically this is a list in a list.

Comment: You can't do IO unless your function returns `IO someType`. Also, you are ignoring the result of `shuffle list` in `main`, so you won't see any shuffled list. There might be other issues.

Comment: I've rolled back your edits because they had invalidated the existing answer. if you have new questions about your new modified code, please post a new question, possibly including the link back to this one for the background, if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Calling the function is not the problem. Your definition of `shuffle` has indentation problems which isn't a problem for the *parser* until it reaches the `main = do` line.

```
import System.IO
import System.Random

shuffle :: [a] -> IO [a]
shuffle list = if length list < 2 then return list else do
   i <- randomRIO (0, length list-1)
   r <- shuffle (take i list ++ drop (i+1) list)
   return (list!!i : r)

main = do  --the problem is in this line
   putStrLn "Enter the number:"  
   number <- getLine  
   let n = (read number :: Int)
   let list = [1..n]
   print list
   shuffled <- shuffle list
   print shuffled
```

Note the additional changes to correctly work with `IO`.

Comment: I change it exactly what you said but after it I got 2 problems more with data type I think